# Problema con imagenes en base de datos springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, imagen

- Les comento soy nuevo manejando imagenes en proyectos de springboot y
  queria saber si me podiran dar una mano con el problema que estoy
  teniedo. El problema en cuestion es que no se si esta guardado la
  imagen en la base de datos SQL, aunque en postman me dice otra cosa.

**Les muestro mi codigo:**

**Controller:**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/imagen")
public class ImagenController {

    @Autowired
    ImagenService imagenService;

    @Autowired
    PacienteService pacienteService;

    @PostMapping("/guardar/{idPaciente}")
    public ResponseEntity<Paciente> guardarImagen(@PathVariable Integer idPaciente,
                                                  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        try {
            Paciente paciente = pacienteService.findPaciente(idPaciente);

            if (paciente != null) {
                String imageName = "imagen_paciente_" + paciente.getId() + "_" + file.getOriginalFilename();

                // Guardar la imagen y actualizar la información del paciente
                imagenService.guardarImagen(idPaciente, file, imageName);
                paciente.setImgUrl(imageName);

                // Actualizar el paciente en la base de datos
                Paciente pacienteActualizado = pacienteService.actualizarPaciente(paciente);

                return new ResponseEntity<>(pacienteActualizado, HttpStatus.OK);
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

**Imagen service**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ImagenServiceImpl implements ImagenService {

    @Value("${file.upload-dir}")
    private String uploadDir;

    @Override
    public void guardarImagen(Integer id, MultipartFile file, String imageName) throws IOException {
        if (file.isEmpty()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("El archivo está vacío");
        }

        // Validar que el archivo sea una imagen (puedes utilizar librerías externas para esta validación)

        Path directorioImagen = Paths.get(uploadDir, id.toString(), imageName);
        Files.createDirectories(directorioImagen.getParent());
        Files.write(directorioImagen, file.getBytes());
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] cargarImagen(Integer id, String imageName) throws IOException {
        Path imagePath = Paths.get(uploadDir, id.toString(), imageName);

        if (!Files.exists(imagePath)) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("La imagen no existe");
        }

        return Files.readAllBytes(imagePath);
    }
}
```

Cuando busco el paciente y encuentro el atributo imagen en postman me trae esto:

> "imgUrl": "imagen_paciente_302_yo cv.jpg",

Pero en la base de datos me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y despues cuando toco el **view**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]